# Npgsql EntityFramework, error - value argument incorrect in ConnectionString - Paramter name: app

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I'm hoping someone can give me an idea as to why I'm getting the above error within my project. I'll try to include as must information as possible.

From my packages.config:

```
<packages>
    <package id="AutoMapper" version="4.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="log4net" version="2.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Npgsql" version="2.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Npgsql.EntityFramework" version="2.2.7" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

The project is database driven and as such I have been able to connect to my PostgreSQL database and created the *.edmx file(s) plus generated the respective controllers, models and repository file(s) for each table. Through this process I have the auto generated connection string ("aaa" == sub name):

```
<add name="aaaPGS" connectionString="metadata=res://*/aaaPGS.csdl|res://*/aaaPGS.ssdl|res://*/aaaPGS.msl;provider=Npgsql;provider connection string=&quot;port=5432;timeout=15;pooling=True;minpoolsize=1;maxpoolsize=20;commandtimeout=20;compatible=2.2.3.0;ApplicationName=aaa;host=aaaVM;database=aaaDB;user id=aaaid;password=aaapwd;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

In my App.config file I have the following settings:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, Npgsql" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, Npgsql.EntityFramework" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Common.Logging" publicKeyToken="af08829b84f0328e" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.2.0" newVersion="2.1.2.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>    
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>

    <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="Npgsql" />
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" support="FF" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  </runtime
```

As you can see I have a SQL connection also, this connection works fine however when I try to perform the same query through postgreSQL I get the following error:

"value argument incorrect in ConnectionString - Paramter name: app"

I don't believe the connection string is in error as it was auto generated but may be I'm wrong? Is there an "app" setting I'm missing? Is this error a by product of something else? Any help much appreciated.